# Reglas de Css3 para transiciones dentro de otras reglas

Tags: css, css3

¿Hay alguna forma de introducir las reglas una dentro de otras? Me explico:

Tengo este html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Prueba de animaciones CSS3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="maestro">
        <div id="in">
            <p id="sup">HOLA</p>
            <p id="inf">HOLA</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

y lo que quiero es que cuando paso el ratón por encima del div "maestro" se cambie de color de fondo y los "p" cambien de posición, de tal forma que el que esta presente "sup" se vaya hacia arriba, y suba el otro "p" con id "inf".
El efecto está conseguido:

Este es el CSS:

```
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#maestro{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    background-color: orange;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    position: relative;
}

#maestro:hover{
    background-color: white;
}

#maestro:hover #sup{
    top: -100%;
}

#maestro:hover #inf{
    top: 0;
}

#in{
    height: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sup{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    color: white;
}

#inf{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    color: orange;
}
```

Entonce, a lo que se refiere mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de hacerlo más sencillo, quiero decir:

```
#maestro:hover{
    background-color: white;
}

#maestro:hover #sup{
    top: -100%;
}

#maestro:hover #inf{
    top: 0;
}
```

Estas reglas meterlas en una sola. Alguna vez me pareció ver algo así:

```
#maestro:hover{
  #inf{
   /*reglas*/
  }
  #sup{
   /*reglas*/
  }
}
```

¿Es posible? O simplemente asimilé mal lo que vi. Me parece un poco molesto tener tantas reglas para el hover del div maestro.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: La forma simplificada que vio es con precompiladores de CSS como  [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Con puro css no se puede simplificar, como te ha dicho Jonhatan podrías usar algún prepocesador, pero con lo poco código que es tu ejemplo tampoco veo muy necesario hacerlo, pero si quieres puedes ver la forma de simplificarlo con Sass o Less.

Comment: Gracias, realmente había hecho ese ejemplo para ver si podía realizarlo de otra manera más simplificada, pero teniendo los datos que me habéis aportado podré hacerlo de mejor manera. gracias.

Answer (score 1):

esa manera de juntar el CSS se llama SASS o SCSS, te quedaría algo así:

```
div#maestro{
    &:hover{
      #inf{
        /*reglas*/
      }
      #sup{
        /*reglas*/
      }
    }
}
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear un archivo con extension scss y usar este programa para que te lo compile en css : http://koala-app.com/

Usando SASS o SCSS, LESS, vas a crear hojas de estilos mucho más rápido.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por la atención prestada, había visto algo de scss pero por lo visto no lo interpreté bien. Tendré que echarlo un ojo. Gracias.